# Cabeçalho pdf com posição absoluta

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Boa tarde a todos!!
Eu estou gerando o pdf de uns dados com o mpdf, e tudo funciona exceto pelo cabeçalho que é gerado e parece estar configurado com 'position:absolute", tem como mudar isso? 
o resto do conteudo está em div....faz alguma diferença?? 
o código que gera o cabeçalho é o:

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($Header,'O');
```

Sem mais,obrigado a todos pela atenção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia a todos!!
Consegui solucionar esse problema aplicando configurações ao construtor da classe da seguinte forma:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', '','','',5,5,70,5);
```

Aplicando essas configurações, consegui posicionar adequadamente o topo!